# What are the legends behind Vaikuntha Chaturdashi?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, vaikuntha

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaikuntha_Chaturdashi

never heard of it till I stumbled on the wiki article.

So what are the legends behind celebrating Vaikuntha Chaturdashi?

Comment: You need to hv the question in the body of the question too ... did not add the festivals tag as I am not sure whether it is one or not